# The application doesn't catch the Position

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, position, phonegap

I'm using PhoneGap to building an application for an university project and i need to catch my position but getCurrentPosition is not running.
I also tried this [MDN example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation/getCurrentPosition), but nothing changed (there is also that warning about secure context I can't find solution to).

Here it is the code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var options = {
        enableHighAccuracy: true,
        timeout: 5000,
        maximumAge: 0
    };

    function success(pos) {
        var crd = pos.coords;

        console.log('Your current position is:');
        console.log(`Latitude : ${crd.latitude}`);
        console.log(`Longitude: ${crd.longitude}`);
        console.log(`More or less ${crd.accuracy} meters.`);
    }

    function error(err) {
        console.warn(`ERROR(${err.code}): ${err.message}`);
    }

    $("#update").click(function() {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success, error, options);
    });
}
```

What am I doing wrong? Is maybe something I have to declare in the file where I click?

**SOLVED**
The problem was with the browser. I solved it accepting manually the position permission, then it also worked in the Android Studio emulator.

Comment: _"that warning about secure context"_ is telling you that the page needs to be using HTTPS in order to use the geolocation API.

Comment: @Turnip What does it mean "needs to be using HTTPS"? I'm running the application using `phonegap serve` (and I need to run it in Android Studio emulator too), I can't change the context...

Comment: If you are using phonegap then you need to mention that in your question and add the appropriate tags.

Comment: I didn't expect it would have been a PhoneGap problem...